# Switch from Ubuntu 2D to Ubuntu

Tags: unity, login, login-screen, ati, 3d

While loging in I chosed "Ubuntu" but when launch My Unity receive message "Ubuntu running in 2D mode..." and some options in compizConfig are disabled.
I am instaled ati radeon proprietary driver and now it's activeted but when try to install post released updates then be a problem with installation and can't activate it.
...and i can't launch Ctalyst Control Centre (as one of the reasons stated- the AMD driver is not functioning properly.)...and still can't switch to Ubuntu 3d.

Comment: You might not have the hardware to run compiz.

Comment: hp probook 4530s,ati radeon 6490m (Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci) and intel hd integrated...

Answer (score 1):

Run *"Additional Driver"* from application menu and install the one *"recommended"* then reboot.It should work for you.If you still stuck, edit your post.